# Issue:Sonar Scanner cli downloading plugins in jenkins for languages other than typescript

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I have set up sonar scanner on jenkins 2 with sonarqube server version 5.6. After running sonar analysis from jenkins, I observed that the multiple plugins are downloaded. Even though the language of the project is set to ts i.e typescript, sonar scanner is still downloading plugins of other languages viz. c-sharp, java, jasvascript. The issue here is slow scanning and unnecessary overload on network. How to limit the download to typescript plugin only?[image]

This is how configuration file look like.

```
sonar.projectKey=uitk4-dev:master
sonar.projectName=UITK4 test
sonar.projectVersion=1.0 
sonar.sources=./src/app/uitk/components
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.exclusions=/**.spec.ts
sonar.language=ts
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
```

Comment: Do you need those plugins for other projects? As an admin you can de-install the plugins not needed.

Comment: `sonar.profile` is deprecated, so it's not surprising that plugin download would ignore its presence.

Comment: @JeroenHeier yes the plugins are needed for other projects but not this project as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam: Couldn't get you. Is this meant to happen? Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Yes, this is meant to happen.